# How can I extract parts of a URL using regular expressions in Perl?

Tags: perl, url

The general format of a URL is
`scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id`

While domain (and possible other parts of the URL) may contain Unicode characters, in the following we assume that only ASCII characters are used. Furthermore, we assume that

> - `scheme` only consists of letters `a–z` and `A–Z`;
> - `domain` does not contain `:`, `?`, `#` or `/`;
> - `port` is a natural number, `:port` is optional;
> - `path` does not contain `?` or `#`, `path` is optional;
> - `query_string` does not contain `#`, `?query_string` is optional;
> - `fragment_id` can contain arbitrary characters, `#fragment_id` is optional.

Here is my code:

```
@urls = (
    "http://www.example.com/",
    "http://www80.local.com:80/",
    "https://www.ex221.ac.uk:442/perl/rulez?all+q#all.time");

foreach (@urls) {
    print "URL: $_\n";
    ($scheme,$domain,$port,$path,$query,$fragment) = (/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)/);
    print "SCHEME: $scheme, DOMAIN: $domain, PORT: $port\n";
    print "PATH: $path\n"; print "QUERY: $query\n";
    print "FRAGMENT: $fragment\n\n";
}
```

How to change the regular expression in the code above so that it correctly separates the five components of a URL and use the sample URLs to test that it works as expected.

Comment: [URI::Split](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/URI-1.67/lib/URI/Split.pm) may be of interest to you.

Comment: The purpose of your homework assignment is to familiarize yourself with character classes. Presumably, you are taking this class because you want to learn Perl. Therefore, it would be to your benefit to actually sit down and read `perldoc perlrecharclass`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend that you use the [URI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI):

```
use URI;

my @urls = (
    "http://www.example.com/",
    "http://www80.local.com:80/",
    "https://www.ex221.ac.uk:442/perl/rulez?all+q#all.time");

foreach (@urls) {
    my $uri = URI->new($_);
    print "URL: $_\n";
    print "SCHEME: ", $uri->scheme, "\n";
    print "DOMAIN: ", $uri->host, "\n";
    print "PORT: ", $uri->port, "\n";
    print "PATH: ", $uri->path, "\n";
    print "QUERY: ", $uri->query, "\n";
    print "FRAGMENT: ", $uri->fragment, "\n";
}
```

Comment: The OP is taking a class, and was given a homework, presumably intended to get students to familiarize themselves with character classes in regular expressions. Using this answer defeats the purpose of the homework assignment. The OP's original single character captures, `(.)`, lazy (and not the good kind), and this will make the OP even lazier.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about a homework. The OP may understand that there is different ways to handle his problem (Perl goal). If it was a homework, perhaps the teacher could have chosen a better example

Comment: The wording of the question is obvious. Your answer is fine for general use, but homework assignments have specific purposes geared towards learning things one step at a time, and this defeats the purpose. I am just pointing that out.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, Feel free to post an answer that you think is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (reference manual) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) (tutorial).

That said, the following is all the information you need to complete your assignment.

To match any of a number of characters, you can use character class.

```
[abcdef]      # Matches a, b, c, d, e or f
```

You can use ranges of letters.

```
[a-zA-Z]      # Matches any lowercase or uppercase letter
```

To match any characters except some, start the class with `^`.

```
[^abcdef]     # Matches any character except a, b, c, d, e or f
```

If you follow something with `*`, it means zero or more of that something.

```
ab*c          # Matches ac, abc, abbc, abbbc, ...
```

Don't forget to escape special characters with `\` if you don't want their special meaning.

```
ab\*c         # Matches ab*c
```